# Importação de arquivo txt no PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: sql, postgresql, importação

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema: 
Tenho um arquivo no formato txt com a seguinte informação:

```
1;Helder;Masculino;GO
2;João;Masculino;RJ
3;Maria;Feminino;PR
4;Pedro;Masculino;MA
```

Eu usei esse exemplo para testar a importação para o postgres 9.6, porém quando eu uso o comando

```
COPY clientes FROM 'C:/clientes.txt' USING DELIMITERS ';'
```

ele só importa os dados se o campo id estiver como varchar. Quando eu crio uma tabela com o campo id como integer ele sempre dá a mensagem

> invalid input syntax for integer

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo? Também tentei alterar a coluna da tabela de varchar para integer com o seguinte comando

```
ALTER TABLE clientes ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer USING id::INTEGER
```

ocorreu o mesmo erro citado anteriormente.

Comment: Em alguma linha o primeiro campo a esquerda vem em branco?

Comment: Não, todas as linhas tem apenas números inteiros

Answer (score 2):

Para poder contornar essa situação o que pode fazer é criar uma procedure, nessa procedure criar uma tabela temporária, e fazer a importação desse arquivo na tabela temporária, feito isso, faça insert com select da tabela temporária para tabela oficial.

Dessa forma irá conseguir manipular os dados.